# target="_blank" not working in Google Chrome on mobile devices (Android)

Tags: html, google-chrome, tags

I used the  tag to link a pdf (which is stored in a folder in my website) with the attribute target="_blank", but it doesn't work on mobile devices (android)

My code:

```
<a href="/catalogue/catalogue.pdf" target="_blank">Catalogue</a>
```

This works just fine on desktop, it opens the pdf in a new tab of the browser, as it should with the attribute target="_blank".
**HOWEVER**, I tested this on mobile and the result was:
It works on iPhone using safari, BUT it doesn't work on Android using Google Chrome. Instead of opening the pdf in a new tab it automatically downloads the file.

Is there any way to change this behaviour?

I've also tried using target="about:blank" instead, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try using the rel=”noopener” or rel=”noreferrer” link attributes for every link.

The rel=”noopener” link attribute prevents the linked site from receiving access to the original web page that is linking out. This prevents the linked site from taking control or otherwise influencing the linking site.

The rel=”noreferrer” link attribute hides the referrer information from the site that is being linked to. When a site visitor clicks a rel=”noreferrer” link, the site being linked to won’t know what site referred the visitor.

For example, if you code a link like this:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/" target="_SEJ" rel="noreferrer">
```

The above link will open in a brand new browser tab.
For further guidance do visit this site:
https://www.searchenginejournal.com/blank-link-attribute/435883/#close